# How to know in a 2 form situation that I am using correct data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am planning on creating an app which could be used to fill out internship information.

There are 2 forms, first of all student fills out their side of the form. After student entry, info will be passed to db and random url will be generated (different url for every student and their counterpart).

When other counterpart(company's represantitive) visits the url they will be rendered the second form and after they have filled it the info will be also sent to the db.

My questions are:

> 1) which way it would be the best to assure that the right info about student and company could be merged and therefore make pdf of it.
>   I wouldnt want to mismatch one students info with totally wrong companys info.
>
> 2) Which way it will be the best to merge this info so I could make a pdf.

I have thought of checking the randomly generated url to assure both counterparts should be merged, by also inserting the url to student table and check it against the url.

Please don't suggest me to use only one form and maybe use socket, 2 forms is only viable option for me.

Going to use express and sequelize with mysql.

Cheers.

Comment: Few key points are missing here. Is there any chance any student can intern under multiple company ?. Under a single company, is there any case that student have to fill two form ? If has to, how the second entry identifies ?. What are these forms called, any specific name ? ( inaguration form / exit interview form ?)

Comment: @RatulSharker No, students canno´t intern under multiple company. There shouldn´t be a case where student has to fill out the second form. The form is filled out by student at first and then someone from the company can fill out their side via the generated url. Those two forms are there to gain information for internship contract.